# Using bash: how to split file according to input file line content?

Tags: shell, file, split

I've got some big text log files. The content is like:

```
Begin to work
Load library
Start
TEXTLOG
Checking
ok
TEXTLOG
Start process
Starting node
ok
TEXTLOG
Stop node
TEXTLOG
```

In this file the lines "TEXTLOG" serves as delimeter, so I wish to split this file into several smaller files, using "TEXTLOG" as EOF indicator, so I should files:

file1:

```
Begin to work
Load library
Start
```

file2:

```
Checking
ok
```

file3:

```
Start process
Starting node
ok
```

file4:

```
Stop node
```

How can I achieve this using shell?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS="\nTEXTLOG\n" '{print > "file"++c}' file
```

`RS` is the record separator and allows to get the content of each file at once.

Answer (score 2):

Using csplit:

```
csplit --suppress-matched file "/TEXTLOG/" "{*}"
```

- `--suppress-matched` makes sure the TEXTLOG separator is not included in the output
- `"{*}"` tells csplit to run the matching pattern not just once, but throughout the entire file

Comment: seems my csplit on linux/mac doesn't support --suppress-matches. How did you try?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 18.04. `csplit --version` gives me `csplit (GNU coreutils) 8.28`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
awk 'BEGIN{c=1}/^TEXTLOG/{c++;next} {print > "file"c}' file 
ls
```